# How Long do I have to wait

Tags: carbonation

I am a pumpkin spice porter; I am going straight to a keg. After I add my priming sugar will the CO2 carbonate my beer so i can drink it immediatly

Answer (score 2):

It will take around 2 weeks at room temp after you prime your keg for it to be carbed and ready.  After you prime it, apply some CO2 from your tank to seal the keg so that the CO2 produced by priming doesn't escape.